# Symantec Messaging Gateway brightmail

Tags: symantec, symantec-endpoint-protection, messaging

our Symantec Messaging Gateway birghtmail broke yesterday, the issue no one can login into the script
 I'm just a normal tech at medium clinic, our system administrator rank quit the job, and now everybody is looking at me to fix it. I do have minor experience, Wordpress small Linux experience..
can anyone tell me the location of the config files? so I can access the database to see what's going on? and the log location anything I can check.
I see a lot of files, but I failed to locate the config.php or something like that, to check if it's correctly anything

thank you

Comment: OK, here's a valuable lesson to learn: Know when to call the vendor for help. This is what I'd suggest that you do. If you have to pay to open a support case then that's what has to be done.